# Why my createdElement is doubling in reactjs useEffect()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cursor, addeventlistener, use-effect

So my issue here is quite simple but you don't have to understand the others codes just only the useEffect() parts..

My custom mousecursor text is doubling when I tried to hover the `text`

here is the lines of codes.

```
    const cursorIntro = document.querySelector(".cursor");
    const options = document.querySelector(".introduction .nav-options");

    options.addEventListener("mousemove", function s(e) {
      var rect = options.getBoundingClientRect();
      var x = e.clientX - rect.left; //x position within the element.
      var y = e.clientY - rect.top;
      cursorIntro.style.left = x + "px";
      cursorIntro.style.top = y + "px";
    });
    function OnSelect() {
      const optionsSelection = document.querySelectorAll(".options");
      optionsSelection.forEach((elem, i) => {
        // console.log(elem.children[1].children[0].children[0])
        elem.children[1].children[0].children[0].addEventListener(
          "mouseleave",
          () => {
            cursorIntro.removeChild(cursorIntro.lastChild);
            // cursorIntro.innerHTML = ""
          }
        );

        elem.children[1].children[0].children[0].addEventListener(
          "mouseenter",
          () => {
            // elem.children[1].children[0].children[0].classList.add('')
            const createElement = document.createElement("h4");
            createElement.innerText =
              elem.children[1].children[0].children[0].dataset.name;
            cursorIntro.appendChild(createElement);
          }
        );
      });
    }

    OnSelect();
```

As you see I have a custom mousecursor on it and because that is where I want to append the text when it hover the `text` elements.

This is inside the useEffect() when I'm calling it...but one that I wasn't sure is that I only call back once the `addEventListener` per each.

The reason I used `createElement` because if I used innerHTML without using a `createElement` I can't add another some items because my plan here is to added something more in `mousecursor`

THIS IS THE [CODEPEN](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-tdd-pye8sw?file=/src/App.jsx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to index.js and replace StrictMode to React.Fragment, in dev mode react re-renders twice

Comment: I have tried and it works well, check this: https://codesandbox.io/s/pensive-keldysh-md91qz?file=/src/index.js

Comment: it still doubled to me??

Comment: oh i know now its working but why? Whats difference of StrictMode and Fragments?

Comment: and why can't I just use Strictmode instead of fragments??

Comment: The reason why this happens is an intentional feature of the React.StrictMode. It only happens in development mode and should help to find accidental side effects in the render phase.